# How does the Cortex M0+ processor use the AHB-Lite interface to fetch instruction and data?

Tags: cortex, cortex-m0+, ahb

How does the Cortex M0+ processor use the AHB-Lite interface to fetch instructions and data? Are instruction fetches done always using NONSEQ? How does it fetch data from memory (using burst or NONSEQ transfers)?

Answer (score 2):

From the ARM M0+ manual, revision r0p1:

**AHB-Lite interface**
Transactions on the AHB-Lite interface are always marked as non-sequential.